# How to let a signed in user create a document in firestore (SDK Web version 9 modular)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to let a signed-in users create a document on the Firestore Database.
For that I want to use the secureToken which gets created by Firebase Authentication after a user logs in with the email/password method.

In the Firebase Realtime Database for example, I can just make a post request with axios where I include the secureToken like this:

```
axios.post('https://project_name.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/posts.json?auth='
+ token, postData)
```

and in the Rules of the Realtime Database I have:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

So that works fine so far.

But with the SDK 9 with the modular approach I don't know how to pass on the secureToken.

Here is the addDoc request:

```
const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), { postData })
```

I was reading the cloud-documentation for hours, but couldn't find out how to proceed from here.

Only found this for adding data in general:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

and this for securely query data:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Firebase SDK for authentication as well then you don't need to add any token. The SDK will check for auth state and do that for you.

```
const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), { postData })
```

The above operation will add a document in `posts` collection if your Firestore security rules allow the current user to write there.

---

Are you using REST API for authentication as well? Then you you might have to use [REST API for Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) as well and pass the auth token yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Yes at the moment I'm still using the REST API for authentication, but will change now.

Comment: @Stefan in that case you would have to use REST API for Firestore as well or somehow log user in via the SDK as well.